# Fastest rate at which CANopen PDOs are received

Tags: pdo, can-bus, canopen

Assuming the highest baud rate, what is the highest rate at which PDOs are received?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the length of the PDO and the number of PDOs per message. The ratio between transported data and protocol overhead is best when you use the full eight bytes of one CAN message.

- If you want high troughput, use all eight bytes of one message
- If you want the highest possible frequency use as few data bits as possible

A rule of thumb:

Eight bytes of a payload result in a CAN message of about 100 bit length.
With 1 Mbit/s maximum baud rate you can achieve about 10000 messages per second.